# Regular expression to not allow all same digits separated by hyphen

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Using the following regex:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{3}-\d{1}$
```

It works for the pattern but I need to validate all numbers not same even after hyphen (-).

Example

```
0000-0 not allowed (because of all are same digits)
0000-1 allowed
1111-1 not allowed (because of all are same digits)
1234-2 allowed
```

Comment: `if value == "0000-0" : print("nope")`

Comment: if there is one value to exclude, seems a regex is overkill

Comment: If there's more than one value and you're literally just looking for zeros separated by a single hyphen, `.indexOf("0-0") > -1` seems more fitting than a regex as well.

Comment: I have been trying with the below format works for few cases but its failed ^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{8}-(?!\1+$)\d{1}$ as part of the response I will give the regex to the caller to validate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using [back references](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), this problem becomes fairly easy (and thankfully js regex supports this).

The regex below matches only the invalid inputs.

```
^(\d)\1+-\1$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cgykDC/1)

```
^     - Start of line
(\d)  - create a capturing group in the first digit (important for the next part to work)
\1+   - back reference group 1 (\d+) and match it one or more times
-     - match a hyphen
\1    - back reference group 1
$     - end of line
```

Then for the JS side, if the regex matches you know the input was invalid.

```
const inputs = [
'0000-0',
'0000-1',
'1111-1',
'1234-2'
];

const regex = /^(\d)\1+-\1$/;

inputs.forEach(item => {
 if (item.match(regex)) {
    console.log(item + ' - INPUT NOT ALLOWED')
 } else {
    console.log(item + ' - VALID INPUT')
 } 
});
```

[JS Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yud6se8r/)

**EDIT**

To handle the new requirements, you can just or the regex to another regex checking the entire length.

```
^(?:(\d)\1+-\1$|.{7,})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vCX15O/1)

And since it sounds like you're using Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String[] lines = {
                "0000-0",
                "0000-1",
                "1111-1",
                "1234-2",
                "1234567-2",
                "1234-26"
        };

        String pattern = "^(?:(\\d)\\1+-\\1$|.{7,})";
        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        for(String line : lines) {
            System.out.print(line);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(" - INVALID");
            }else {
                System.out.println(" - VALID");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

** Output **

```
0000-0 - INVALID
0000-1 - VALID
1111-1 - INVALID
1234-2 - VALID
1234567-2 - INVALID
1234-26 - INVALID

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Its not working as expected using Java tested in (https://regex101.com/) and its even not allowed the valid cases like 11112-1 and its allowed more digits but we have upped bound 4 before the (-) total 6 chars including (-).

Comment: The regex is matching the invalid cases, not the valid. Using a simple if you can reverse the regex match. This creates a simpler regex than the alternative. I also adjusted for the max length. See the updated answer for help.